# Creating a dynamic dropdown, after a selection has been made

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, textbox, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown after a dropdown has been selested (in asp.net vb)

For example: I have a dropdown question that asks: What brand of car do you drive (Toyota, Ford, Honda, Nissan, Chevrolet)

When the brand is selected I want another dropdown to appear under it with new chocies

For example: If Nissan is chosen, the second dropdown will be populated (from the database) with (Altima, Maxima, etc...)

And in some cases I would like a text box to appear, but If I can figure out the dropdown portion, I am sure I can figure out the textbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Ajax, you could use the AjaxControlToolkit's [CascadingDropdownExtender](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CascadingDropDown.aspx). Here is the direct link to it: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: @Tim You should put that in as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested in the comments, i'm putting this in as an answer*

If you are using Ajax, you could use the AjaxControlToolkit's [CascadingDropdownExtender](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CascadingDropDown.aspx).

Here is the direct link to it: 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

And here is a Video-Tutorial: http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-cascadingdropdown-control-extender

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ajaxdropdownlist.aspx

There are quite a few examples if you look on Google.

http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

In the DropDownList selected index changed event, you can do whatever you want. You can show the other DropDownList or the other TextBox and you can also bind the DropDownList with the items you want.

Your code could look like:

```
ddlModel.DataSource = GetModels(ddlCar.SelectedValue);
ddlModel.Visible = true;
```